# GetSerialNumber gives different value than SerialNumber in an X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have a certificate data (byte array):

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
var serialBytes = cert.GetSerialNumber();
var serialString = cert.SerialNumber;
```

when converting `serialBytes` to hex format:

```
BitConverter.ToString(serialBytes).Replace("-","")
```

it gives a different value than `serialString`

Answer (score 1):

Because you should read the documentation:

> [X509Certificate.GetSerialNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getserialnumber?view=net-5.0)
> Returns the serial number of the X.509v3 certificate as an array of bytes in **little-endian order**.

> [X509Certificate2.SerialNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.serialnumber?view=net-5.0)
> Gets the serial number of a certificate as a **big-endian** hexadecimal string.

Comment: I read it after posting the question :)